# How to I get perldoc to find my modules in perl/site/lib?

Tags: perl, deployment, perldoc

**Update**: My problem seems to have solved itself. Not sure what's going on. Sorry for the false alarm.

My understanding is that `perl/lib` is reserved for the core Perl distribution and that I should be putting my own modules in `perl/site/lib`. However, when I do that, `perldoc` does not find my modules. It does find modules that I put in `perl/lib`. It also finds modules that ActivePerl's `ppm` utility installs in `perl/site/lib`. What do I need to do differently so that my modules in `perl/site/lib` will be visible to `perldoc`? Currently, my "deployment process" consists of nothing more than copying a bunch of `.pm` files to `perl/site/lib` -- I suspect that's the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Update your [`PERL5LIB` environment variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlrun.html) to include `perl/site/lib/perl5` and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Do your modules actually contain pod?  If they don't, perldoc will skip them (unless you specify the -m option).